# MySQL - phpMyAdmin: #1106 Table xxxxxx doesn't exist but they appear in the schema

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm building a project in PHP in localhost and today when I started to work in my project I found a very weird trouble.

When I ran the project in my browser (Chrome) I found the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'garnica_admongym.suscripciones' doesn't exist' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/GAR_AdmonGym/models/SuscripcionesModel.php:42 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/GAR_AdmonGym/models/SuscripcionesModel.php(42): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/GAR_AdmonGym/controllers/GetSuscripciones_Controller.php(8): SuscripcionesModel::getAll('1') #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/GAR_AdmonGym/admonsys/gymadmon.php(18): GetSuscripciones_Controller::GetAll() #3 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/GAR_AdmonGym/models/SuscripcionesModel.php on line 42

When I ran the phpMyAdmin I found my DB index normal (all the tables were appeared normally as you can see in the image below), but when I clicked to any table, the PMA thrown me the next error

> 1146 - The table xxxxxxxxx doesn't exist

And also the trouble comes worst when I try to run the export command to save all the tables and the relationships I made and when I execute that, the PMA throws me that there are not tables to export!

So, what happened here? I don't want to create again that DB :(

I attach the screenshot of that trouble

[image: As you can see at the right of the image, the DB table schema looks good]

Comment: Could someone have dropped the table while your session was open? Have you tried refreshing?

Comment: Of course! But it's to weird because looks like my DB were truncated but that's not the case. Literally, my tables doesn't exists

Comment: An error like this can occur if the files in the files in the MySQL data directory are affected. Any chance you did some operation on the files themselves, such as trying to copy from one server to another or restoring the files from backup? Can you run a disk check (fsk, chkdsk, etc) on the drive?